# Nuget Package (StyleCop.Analyzers) doesn't work on project reload

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, nuget, stylecop

I've used the Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio 2017 to install StyleCop.Analyzers, which I'm very happy with. However, every time I close and re-open Visual Studio, StyleCop is no longer listed in the analyzers.

The only way I can get it back to analyzing my code is to uninstall it from Nuget, then reinstall it, and go through the process of enabling/disabling rules per that project. After that, it will work properly. How do I keep StyleCop.Analyzers working when I restart Visual Studio?

Comment: That's an interesting problem you're seeing, and I don't think a common one. You may want to submit a bug report to the Visual Studio team, with details about the specific build of Visual Studio, a specific set of steps (or repro) that reproduces the issue, and any other details specific to your machine that might be causing this.

Comment: Looks like the issue was that I was running Visual Studio using Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue was Unity, so this is a very niche problem. There are a couple attempts at solving it listed here:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-and-stylecop-analyzers.639784/

Comment: Hi Brettins, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)